# Hide clicked/swiped element (ng-click/ng-swipe-right)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I've got follow code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.cContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cHeaders {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.cHeader {
  background-color: rgb(141, 141, 142);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.cThemeHeader {
  width: 300px;
}
.cItemHeader {
  width: 300px;
}
.cCountHeader {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center
}
.cData {
  display: flex;
}
.cRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cItemRow {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
.cBox {
  background-color: rgb(208, 229, 199);
  color: #4a7f35;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.cTheme {
  width: 300px;
}
.cItem {
  background-color: white;
  color: #4a7f35;
  border: 1px solid #4a7f35;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 18px;
}
.cCount {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #4a7f35;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  .cBox {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .cItem {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Arbeitsplanung</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("myApp", ['ngTouch']).controller("myController", function($scope) {
      $scope.dataList = [{
        id: 1,
        count: 0,
        text: 'Leistung nach Bedarf',
        items: [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'bei Bedarf'
        }]
      }, {
        id: 2,
        count: 0,
        text: 'Leistung je 2 stündlich',
        items: [{
          id: 1,
          text: '11:00'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          text: '15:00'
        }]
      }, {
        id: 3,
        count: 0,
        text: 'Leistung auf einen fixen Zeitpunkt',
        items: [{
          id: 1,
          text: '15:00'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          text: '16:00'
        }]
      }];
      $scope.hideBox = function(event) {
        $(event.target).hide();
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="./removeItem.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cContent">
    <div class="cHeaders">
      <div class="cHeader cThemeHeader">Katalog</div>
      <div class="cHeader cItemHeader">Plan</div>
      <div class="cHeader cCountHeader">Ist</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cData" ng-repeat="data in dataList">
      <div class="cThemeRow">
        <div class="cBox cTheme">{{data.text}}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="cBox cItemRow">
        <div ng-repeat="item in data.items" class="cItem" ng-click="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox($event);" ng-swipe-right="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox($event);">{{item.text}}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="cCountRow">
        <div class="cBox cCount">{{data.count}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click on the white box (or swipe it on tablet), I would like to hide the clicked/swipped element. I tried it with $event.target, but it seems not to work at all. Has someone an idea, how to hide the current clicked/swipped element (ng-click, ng-swipe-right)? Thanks.

**SOLUTION:** It works, my error was follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items" class="cItem" ng-click="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox(this);" ng-swipe-right="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox($event);">{{item.text}}</div>
```

I used `this` in the ng-click in case of `$event`.

Comment: LOOK AT THE EDIT, I'VE FOUND THE ERROR. THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** It works, my error was follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items" class="cItem" ng-click="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox(this);" ng-swipe-right="data.count = data.count + 1; hideBox($event);">{{item.text}}</div>
```

I used `this` in the `ng-click` in case of `$event` (look at the edit in my question). It works fine with `$(event.target).hide();`. Anyway thanks.